# Should I select from database only useful columns?

Tags: database, entity-framework, hibernate

I understand, that to optimize my application it is necessary to make row selection in database instead of sending into the application whole tables etc.

But my question is following: When I have table with columns id, name, address and in my application I will just only display name and I will do not work with any other column, should I select only name or it does not matter if I select just all columns from wanted rows?

I ask, because if I understand it correctly, entity framework/hibernate gets all columns from database so it should not make any problem in applications with huge data.

Comment: *I understand it correctly*. No, both EF and NHibernate allow you to fetch *projections* from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should get only the data that you need. If you have 100 columns, and you only need 1 on them, then why select all these extra columns? If you get more data than you need you get more disk reads, more network usage, more CPU used to process the data.

It might not be an issue if the application is small and there is only couple of requests time to time, but if you are talking about large systems with very many requests, all these extra selected columns will degrade your overall performance of the system.